# Expressões regulares para um ou mais números de telefone

Tags: regex

Tenho uma expressão regular que valida telefone celular e fixo, mas o usuário só consegue adicionar um fixou ou um celular, ela não permite adicionar mais de um número.

Como faço pra expressão aceitar mais de um número?

Eu até consigo que ela aceite mais de um número se eu fixar ela dentro de um grupo e repetir, só que aí aceita se eu colocar dois números, se eu coloco 1 não aceita, e eu precisava que aceitasse 1 ou mais números.

```
/^[1-9]{2} (?:[2-8]|9[1-9])[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}$/
```

Exemplo: `11 91111-1111`

---

Utilizo uma ferramenta para criar requisições para usuários. Foi solicitado para que se criasse uma opção para o usuário inserir um ou mais telefones, nesse formato: "11 91111-1111".

Essa ferramenta tem uma opção que eu posso utilizar regex. A expressão que eu estou utilizando acima está correta, porém, ela só permite que o usuário insira apenas um número.

Eu tentei dessa forma também:

```
(/^[1-9]{2} (?:[2-8]|9[1-9])[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}$/) (/^[1-9]{2} (?:[2-8]|9[1-9])[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}$/)
```

Mas aí ela só permite que o usuário insira dois números, não menos ou mais que isso.

Comment: E como seria os exemplos com dois ou mais números de telefone?

Comment: Não entendi, vc quer achar um ou mais número dentro de um input? é no javascript que isso é aplicado?

Comment: Utilizo uma ferramenta para criar requisições para usuários. Foi solicitado para que se criasse uma opção para o usuário inserir um ou mais telefones, nesse formato:11 91111-1111. Essa ferramenta tem uma opção que eu posso utilizar regex. A expressão que eu estou utilizando que eu coloquei na criação do post esta correta, porém, ela só permite que o usuário insira apenas um número. Eu tentei dessa forma também: (/^[1-9]{2} (?:[2-8]|9[1-9])[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}$/) (/^[1-9]{2} (?:[2-8]|9[1-9])[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}$/), mas ai ela só permite que o usuário insira dois números não menos ou mais que isso

Answer (score 3):

A regex correta depende de como os números serão aceitos. Por exemplo, se quiser que eles  estejam na mesma linha e sejam separados por espaço, uma opção seria:

```
^[1-9]{2} (?:[2-8]|9[1-9])[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}( [1-9]{2} (?:[2-8]|9[1-9])[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4})*$
```

Esta regex basicamente se resume a:

```
^regex_numero( regex_numero)*$
```

Ou seja, a regex para o número é a mesma que você usou (`[1-9]{2} etc...`). A ideia é que eu tenha uma ocorrência desta regex (para o caso de ter apenas um número), e depois eu posso ter `( regex_numero)*`.

Repare que logo depois do `(` há um espaço. Isso indica que depois do primeiro número de telefone pode ter um espaço, seguido de outro número. Eu agrupo tudo isso dentro dos parênteses e uso o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`, que significa "zero ou mais ocorrências". Isso quer dizer que todo esse grupo (espaço + outro número de telefone) pode se repetir zero ou mais vezes.

Sendo assim, a regex aceita um ou mais números de telefone no formato indicado, separados por espaço. Exemplos de casos aceitos:

```
11 91129-1231
11 91231-2343 11 2322-4332
15 98221-9540 12 93853-2343 45 4332-0593
```

Veja a regex funcionando no [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Mmwhdw/1/).

---

Outro detalhe importante é o uso dos [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$`, que são respectivamente o início e fim da string. Assim eu garanto que a string só tem o que está na regex (então se tiver qualquer outro caractere antes ou depois dos números, a regex falha).

---

Se quer limitar a quantidade, basta trocar o `*` por algum dos quantificadores `{min,max}`. Ex:

```
^[1-9]{2} (?:[2-8]|9[1-9])[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}( [1-9]{2} (?:[2-8]|9[1-9])[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}){0,3}$
```

Em vez do `*`, eu usei `{0,3}` (no mínimo zero, no máximo 3 ocorrências), o que quer dizer que a sequência "espaço + número" pode se repetir no máximo 3 vezes. Portanto agora a regex aceita entre 1 e 4 números de telefone, separados por espaço.

---

Repetir a regex inteira pode ser meio chato e até causar problemas de manutenção futura (pois uma alteração na regex exigiria uma mudança em 2 lugares).

Caso a ferramenta que você usa suporte [sub-rotinas](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#subroutines), é possível fazer algo assim:

```
^(?<numero>[1-9]{2} (?:[2-8]|9[1-9])[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4})( (?&numero))*$
```

A sintaxe `(?<numero>` define um [*named group*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) cujo nome é `numero`. Em seguida, `(?&numero)` signfica "a mesma regex que foi definida no *named group* `numero`". Assim você não precisa repetir a mesma regex duas vezes ([veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/Mmwhdw/2/) ela funcionando).

Outra opção é usar grupos sem nome:

```
^([1-9]{2} (?:[2-8]|9[1-9])[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4})( (?1))*$
```

Nesse caso, o primeiro número está entre parênteses, e este pode ser referenciado posteriormente através de `(?1)` (que referencia o primeiro par de parênteses - no caso, a expressão que corresponde a um número de telefone).

Importante notar que as sub-rotinas referenciam a mesma expressão (e podem portanto dar *match* em números diferentes), diferente do que acontece com grupos de captura, que referenciam o trecho que foi capturado (e só dariam *match* se o mesmo número se repetisse).

Mas este recurso de sub-rotinas não é suportado em todas as engines/linguagens/ferramentas (e nesse caso, o jeito é repetir a expressão mesmo).